# How to manage domain model or data access model or data transfer model

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In DDD, many models are there:

- Domain model, which is used in busiess or application layer.
- Data access model, which is used in data access or data repository layer.
- Data transfer model (DTO), which is used in presentation layer.

Beacuse of them, the disadvantages raise：

- They violate the DRY principle, beacuse many duplicate fields exist between them and can't avoid.
- They need a lot of irritable mapping to conversion between different layers.

How can we reduce the irritable Models?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, it is about choosing your battles.  One of the main considerations in a Domain-Driven solution is that it is focused on isolating and encapsulation of the domain.  That means that, by that very premise, you are not going to want to use it as an approach in every single project.  You need to have an inherent complexity that you are trying to reduce, and you do so by modeling the needs of the business and the needs of the application independently.  This means that you are not creating a single system, but one or more systems (your application or applications) that are utilizing a consummate subsystem (your domain).

Personally, I do not have the three types of data-bearing classes that you describe in any of my projects.  Instead, I have only my domain model and a view model representation based on each distinct UI requirement.  I have found that the need to have a separate set of persistence classes to be superfluous.  There are several ways to eliminate the need for persistence classes, such as POCOs with code-first EF, object databases/NoSQL, and separation of your read model and write model.  I opt for a combination of the last two, personally, in most cases.

The translation layer between the domain and application/UI is something that I find to be required, because the "truth" that the domain represents is infallible.  But, in order to attain a usable interface into the domain, the application will sometimes have additional or differing requirements to the domain.  That means that this translation layer is not just about field mapping, it is about encapsulation of differing concepts and isolation of usage scenarios.

Since the domain should have absolutely no knowledge of how it is used, that means that there is a *requirement* for translation and it is not something that should be attempted to be worked out of the system.  I have seen people who have used their domain classes directly in the UI, as the actual model, and that is more heinous (in my opinion) than having to create a translation layer.  You are looking at it from the perspective of just being for translation, but remember that it is also about isolation.  Introduction of new concepts, changing of existing concepts, and other changes within the domain can effectively be intercepted in translation to prevent impact in the UI, and vice versa.

That sounds trivial, but in an enterprise setting, it is not uncommon for there to not be just a single application that utilizes the domain, but multiple applications.  Consider the possibility that your domain is serving a desktop application, a web application, and a REST API.  Each of those will have their own specific application requirements that are separate from your business requirements.  They also will likely want to represent the domain differently from each other.  This means that each of them will likely have things such as different validation requirements, different views into your domain, and unique application functionality.  Regardless of all of this, the domain remains happily oblivious to it all.  You will have to translate differently for each, somewhere above the domain.

If you are finding that your models are looking exactly like your domain, with a majority of it being one-to-one mappings, you might want to take a step back and look for some other issues that might be occurring.  I find a large number of two-way mappings of singular fields to be a code smell.  Not always, but often, this is an early sign of an anemic domain model.  I personally go as far as to enforce architectural requirements on my domain model, such as requiring that properties be read-only (forcing them to be set through a constructor for existing data and changed through methods on the classes), etc.  It is fairly trivial to write architectural unit tests which will reflect your domain classes to inspect them for possible violations of such rules.  But, the point is if you find translation to be your pain point, make sure that your domain model is not just acting as a data container.  Anemic domain models are an extraordinarily common pitfall in DDD implementations, and with an anemic domain model, there is actually very little benefit to a DDD approach at all, as you are taking the power and responsibility away from the place it should be enforced.

Business requirements should be reflective of the needs of the domain, which is not the same thing as the usage patterns of the domain.  Ideally, you should be telling the domain how you want to change its state, and the domain should be applying the domain logic to allow or disallow those changes.  If you find yourself pulling down a full domain model representation for a part of the domain, translating the entire thing to a model or DTO, modifying that model or DTO, translating it back to the domain representation, and sending the whole thing back in, you likely have a larger problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to review your understanding of DRY.  A good starting point is [DRY is about Knowledge](http://verraes.net/2014/08/dry-is-about-knowledge/) -- Matthias Verraes (2014).

You may also want to look at Gary Bernhardt's 2012 talk [Boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTkzNHF6rMs).

The key idea is this - the DTO model is an API contract between the domain model and the presentation components.  It gives us the freedom to aggressively update/adapt/improve the domain model without breaking the existing presentation component.

Similarly, the data access model is an API contract between the domain and the presentation component.  Not only does this mean that the interface between the domain and persistence is stable, but it also provides a stable contract between the current implementation of the domain model (which writes data today) and *future* implementations of the domain model (which read back that same data tomorrow).

Answer (score 2):

No, there are not many models. There are multiple representations of the same model. This distinction is very important.

In the domain model, the entity is responsible of making sure that it's state is instact. For instance, the `ApprovedAt` property may not be set unless `ApprovedBy` is set at the same time. This is usually done by adding ***behavior*** to the entity. I do it by always setting all property setters to private and then add methods every time the entity need to change state.

The DTO is responsible of transferring state between over application boundaries. But when you do DDD correctly you do not want to transfer the domain entity to the client. You want it to remain safe within the server. Thus the role of the DTO is much more important. You might even have multiple DTOs for the same entity. For instance, I might have a `UserListDTO` which contains a subset for just listing entities and maybe a `UserDetailsDTO` which is designed for the user details page. For writes you just transfer the mutated state or send command influenced DTOs (`ApproveUserDTO`).

Finally it's important that the domain entity isn't forced to be designed in a certain way just to be able to persist it. That's why we have the data entity. It will be design so that everything can be persisted in a efficient way. The user might have a data entity called `User` and one called `UserField` depending on the domain entity design.

The conclusion is that if you models look exactly the same you are doing something wrong (from the perspective of DDD).

Answer (score 2):

**1. This is not about Domain-Driven Design**

Separating models comes with your ancestral n-layer architectural style. It dates back long before DDD was around.

**2. You don't have to have that many models**

If your application is simple enough, you can ditch some of them.

"Data access model" comes to mind first. It's only a recent addition to the DDD paraphernalia. But you can do without just as well, with a minor impact on your domain model.

And guess what, you may even find out that you don't need a rich domain model at all... Some applications are just better off as CRUD.

**If you find something "irritable", get rid of it** and see for yourself what the benefits/drawbacks are. Code police won't come knocking at your workplace and lock you up for favoring simplicity over so-called orthodoxy.